# Regression techniques for capped independent variables

Tags: regression

Suppose you are trying to predict height ($y$) based on age ($x$). A straight linear regression won’t work well, since humans stop growing at a certain age. This suggests instead trying to model height as something like:

$y = w\cdot \mathrm{squash}(x, a, b) + w_0$

where

$\mathrm{squash}(x,a,b) = \max(a, \min(x,b))$

In general, when trying to predict some dependent variable $y$ from dependent variables $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$, some of which you expect to display "squash"-characteristics like this, it seems a good idea to try to model $y$ by something like:

$y = w_0 + \sum_{i=1}^n w_i\cdot\mathrm{squash(x_i, a_i, b_i)}$

I'm wondering what regularized techniques exist to estimate $\vec{w}, \vec{a}, \vec{b}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little bit tough, because of the kinks in your `squash` function. A related idea would be to use something like $\tan^{-1}\{(x-a)/b\}$ in place of `squash`, and use nonlinear regression to fit the model. This would be a similar idea, but smoothes out the transitions between affecting the response and not affecting it. Other S-shaped curves could be used in place of the arc tangent, e.g., logistic, cumulative normal, or even something not symmetrical around its inflection point.

#### Addendum

If it really is height versus age, you probably don't want an S-shaped curve. Something more like $w_0+w_1(1-e^{-ax})$, with one less parameter, provides for rapid initial growth, slowing down later.

Answer (score 0):

Realistic height-age curves are ... well, [*curved*](http://www.chartsgraphsdiagrams.com/HealthCharts/height-2-20-boys.html), rather than like your linear-with-a-barrier function.

As you see, the population curves show several slowdowns and speedups and are not likely to be well-fitted by an overly-simple functional form.

Individual growth curves (when taken at reasonably high frequency, say monthly) tend to be a little more complex, with a number of growth spurts and slow patches.

Your multiple-regression situation looks like you have an additive model with natural linear splines in each variable, and also estimate the knot-positions. This can be treated in a number of ways, for example as a nonlinear/partially linear least squares problem.

But if your motivation is growth curves, it doesn't strike me as a close match.